# cy.wait() timed out waiting 5000ms for the 1st request to the route

Tags: javascript, cypress

I am new to `Cypress` and  i am checking HTML page. I need to test the login authentication and to log `XHR` body.
So, I wrote a test like :

```
describe('Login test', function () {

    it("Test description", () => {
        cy.server();
        cy.visit("login");

        cy.route({
            method: "POST",
            url: '/login'
        }).as("login");

        cy.get('#username')
            .type(Cypress.env('Account'));

        cy.get('#password')
            .type(Cypress.env('Password'));

        cy.get('#login')
            .click();

        cy.wait("@login").then(xhr => {
            cy.log(JSON.stringity(xhr.response.body));
        });

    });
});
```

The test fail with a log of :

CypressError: Timed out retrying: cy.wait() timed out waiting 5000ms for the 1st request to the route: 'route_login'. No request ever occurred.

can any one help please ?

Answer (score 3):

Try this :

```
describe('Login test', function () {

it("Test description", () => {
    cy.server();


    cy.route({
        method: "POST",
        url: '/login'
    }).as("login");

    cy.wait("@login", {timeout: 15000});

    cy.visit("login");

    cy.get('#username')
        .type(Cypress.env('Account'));

    cy.get('#password')
        .type(Cypress.env('Password'));

    cy.get('#login')
        .click();

    cy.get("@login").then(xhr => {
        cy.log(JSON.stringity(xhr.response.body));
    });

});

});
```

Comment: https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/3427 - there is an open issue related to your case. Try to read through comments there. It may be helpful.  Jenifer wrote: **"I had the same issue but solved it by moving cy.server(); and cy.route(...); before cy.visit()."**

Comment: Hey. Have you found the solution eventually?

Answer (score 0):

`cy.route` and `cy.server` all both deprecated and should not be used.
combination of `cy.intercept` and `cy.wait` should suffice